# Two-way binding and event delegation in React

Tags: reactjs, events

Is there a way to implement it? When I try to do, react throws warning that I should only use onChange + value attributes, but I would not like to spam event handlers on each element if I already have it on common parent...

Answer (score 0):

Just pass your `onChange` and `value` to child component using props

https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-shadow-wxd0e?file=/src/App.js